# Can a sequence be called convergent/divergent if it has finite number of terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

No explanation required for the question I guess.

Comment: The statement doesn't really make any sense; unless, of course, you're using a different definition. Convergence is defined as $\forall\; \varepsilon > 0, \exists N$ such that $\forall\; n>N, |a_{n}-L|<\varepsilon$. Divergence is the opposite. I guess by an empty argument, the sequence would converge to its last element?

Comment: @ChrisK can't you say that 1,1,1,1,1,.... (n terms)  converges to 1 ?

Comment: @Bach, perhaps. I've never seen convergence used in this context; it seems like a very vacuous argument to me though.

Comment: @StefanSmith : I was just thinking about it myself. And no I do not mean an infinite sequence with a finite number of distinct elements.

Comment: Generally the word "sequence" means infinite sequence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. A finite sequence is convergent.

Call your sequence $\{a_k\}$. It is finite, so it has a last term, say $a_m=M$.

An sequence converges to a limit $L$ if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some integer $N$ such that if $k\ge N$, $|a_k-L|<\epsilon$. However, since your sequence is finite, for any $\epsilon>0$ we just take $N=m$, and it is clearly true that if $k\ge m$, $|a_k-L|=|a_m-L|=0<\epsilon$, since the only possible value for $k$ is $M$ itself.

I hope that was not too confusing.

Comment: I don't think that this application of the definition is correct since when you write $|a_k-L|$ for all $k\ge m$, you are implicitly assuming that $a_k$ for all $k\ge m$ does make sense, which is not true.