# Is the limit of a finite sequence simply its last term?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I haven't dealt with convergence of finite sequences yet and my textbook doesn't say much about this. Using the definition of convergence, I was able to show that the limit of a finite sequence is its last term. I don't know if this is correct. Can you please let me know?

Let $\{a_n \}_{n \in N}$ be a finite sequence where $N \subset \mathbb{N}$. Denote the number of elements in $N$ by $\bar{N}$. Now we know that for all $\epsilon > 0, \ \exists \ \bar{N} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $ n \geq \bar{N}, \ \mid a_\bar{N}-a_n \mid<\epsilon$. But this is the definition of a sequence that converges to $a_\bar{N}$. So does this mean that the limit of a finite sequence is simply the last element of the sequence?

Comment: And by this logic, is the limit of a sequence with one element $\{a_1\}$ just $a_1$?

Comment: Seems quite unusual to take the limit of a finite sequence. But the definition you mentioned seems to be conform to the definition of a limit

Comment: I'm not voting to close, but note this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600795/can-a-sequence-be-called-convergent-divergent-if-it-has-finite-number-of-terms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically yes, I think, but it is not too interesting to consider convergence of a sequence that terminates after finitely many terms.

If $a_1,...,a_{n_0}$ is a finite sequence indexed by $I = \{1,...,n_0\}$ and $x = a_{n_0}$, then the criterion for convergence $a_n \to x$ is automatically satisfied: $$(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists N_0 \in I)(n \geqslant N_0, \, n \in I \,\, \Longrightarrow  \,\,|a_n-x|<\varepsilon).$$ No matter what $\varepsilon$ you pick setting $N_0 = n_0$ will work.

Typically the index set is $I = \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I also observed that setting $N_0=n_0$ does the trick for all 
$\epsilon>0$, but I wasn't sure if I was misunderstanding something. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using this result to prove that any bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence? One could simply define a subsequence of the convergent sequence to contain one element. Then, by the same argument we have been making, this subsequence with one element converges to the one element, and thus, i have shown that a bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence (although this could also work for an unbounded sequence). Is there a flaw in my logic? I think there is. I just don't know what it is. Or is the question poorly specified, thereby, allowing this to be a proof.

Comment: If you are referring to the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, then I don't suggest you use finite sequences. That isn't really what the theorem is asserting anyway: when the theorem says *subsequence* it is understood to mean *infinite subsequence*. Knowing that there are finite subsequences that converge tells you pretty much nothing about the space you are studying. Knowing the existence of infinite subsequences tells you much more

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will work out a proof for infinite subsequences.

Comment: No. If the sequence is $a = (1,2,3,4)$ and $N_0 = 1$, then $10 > N_0$ but $a_{10}$ has no meaning.

Answer (score 3):

The limit is usually only defined for an infinite sequence, not a finite sequence.

The usual definition:

> For all $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that for every $n > N$, $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$

assumes $a_n$ to be defined for every $n > N$, which is not the case for a finite sequence.

If you modify it to say "... for every $n > N$ for which $a_n$ is defined, ...", then the limit of a finite sequence could be anything at all.  There's no particular reason for it to be the last member of the sequence: $L = $"a unicorn"
 works just as well if $N$ is greater than the index of the last member of the sequence.

Comment: I don't see why your argument in the last paragraph holds. Also, the definitions I have come across are different than yours. They usually read : For all $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that if $n \geq N$, $\mid a_n-L \mid < \epsilon$.

Comment: @lasoon are you familiar with vacuuously true statemenst.  Le $k =$ the number of terms in the sequence.  Then let $N > k$.  Then for all $n > N$ it is true that $|a_n - 57.39| < \epsilon$ because there is no $a_n$.  ...

Comment: @fleablood Yes, but it doesn't necessarily hold if you set $N=k$ and take $\mid a_n - 57.39 \mid$ for $n \geq N$. The definition in my post is analogous to letting $N=k$ and taking the difference for $n \geq N$. Is my definition wrong? Should $n \geq N$ be switched with $n>N$ and $N = k$ be switched with $N > k$ ?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use $\ge$ or $>$.  $n > N$ is the same as $n \ge N+1$ (for integers).

Comment: On the other hand.  The "for any n" refers to the n, not the a_n.  so "there is no a_n" could go either way.  Frankly I don't think it mayters.

Comment: @fleablood $n>N \implies |a_n-57.39|$ is not a vacuous statement if $a_n$ is undefined. It is of the form $p \implies FALSE$. a vacuous statement would be of the form $FALSE \implies |a_n-57.39|$